# How to assign "null" when received data is undefined?

Tags: javascript, object, undefined

I am currently working on a project that collects product information of several stores.
I have a problem when I'm assigning the scraped product data to an object that I want to store in a final array. Everything is going well except for when a product does not have an image.

```
 let productData = {
        productId: item.id, 
        title: item.title,
        price: item.price.now,
        unitSize: item.price.unitSize,
        productLink: item.link,
        productImage: typeof item.images[0].url == "undefined" ? null : item.images[0].url,
        availableOnline: item.availableOnline
      }
      productsArray.push(productData)
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to use a ternary operator to check if the value is undefined first. If the value is undefined I want to set the value of productImage to null instead of the whole application failing with the error that it's undefined. I also tried storing the value in a seperate variable first and check for that variable to be undefined or not but that wasn't working either.

Could anyone explain to me why the way I do it now is not working and what I should do in order to make it work?

Comment: The error is most likely that `item.images[0]` is `undefined`, not that `item.images[0].url` is

Comment: @VLAZ if item.images[0] is  undefined  then   item.images[0].url  would be too right?

Comment: if `item.images[0]` is `undefined` then reading any property of it *is an error*. The property is not `undefined`, you cannot even read it.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for the clear answer, this fixed my issue and it's clear for me what went wrong now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does `item.images` always have an array item at position zero? If not, you're trying to get the `url` property from an undefined object, which will throw an error.

You could add to this by first checking that `item.images[0]` exists:

```js
{
  productImage: item.images[0] !== undefined && typeof item.images[0].url == "undefined" ? null : item.images[0].url,
}
```

Better yet, assuming you don't need IE compatibility, you could use [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), and [Nullish Coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) as pointed out by [robertklep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893780/robertklep) in the comments.

```js
{
  productImage: item.images[0]?.url ?? null,
}
```

Comment: Or use `item.images[0]?.url ?? null`